# getActivity is null

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-activity

I'm trying to use a `ListView` in a fragment. But `getActivity()` is null. I have already searched and found many threads about this topic but these were not very helpful. 
Here is my code:

`ListView.java`:

```
package de.listview.example;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class ListViews extends ListFragment {

    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener;

    public void makelist()
    {
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                   "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                   "Linux", "OS/2" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

`MainActivity.java`:

```
public static class ListFragment extends Fragment
{

    Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        mContext = getActivity();
        Log.i("Event", "onAttach called");
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        ListViews lst = new ListViews();
        lst.makelist();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.whitelist_content, container, false);
    }


}

case 2:
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, new ListFragment())
                .commit();
    break;
```

Comment: you should carefully read the documentation for fragment and activity

Comment: `getActivity()` is null because your `Fragment` has not yet been attached to an `Activity`, which means the layout hasn't even inflated yet. This is standard behavior. You should familiarize yourself with the [Fragment lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ListFragment` in the `onAttach()` method your fragment still isn't attached to any `Activity` that's why you're getting a null value.

Change:

```
mContext = getActivity();
```

To:

```
mContext = activity;
```

Or use `getActivity()` inside `onCreateView()` for example.

---

The other problem is you are creating your fragment but it is not attached to any Activity when you use `makeList()` that's why you are getting a null value when using `getActivity()`.

The right way to do that is for example call `makeList()` inside `onCreateView()` of your `ListView` fragment.

Also after creating the fragment you have to add it with:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, lst).commit();
```

You should read about how to work with fragments: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: 've changed it. Unfortunately still get FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException